# Is it possible to install Haskell and non-Haskell packages within a Python/Django app deployed in Heroku?

Tags: python, django, bash, haskell, heroku

My Django application uses packages associated with Haskell, such as `HLint`, and some non-Haskell packages such as `graphviz`. I use the `shlex` command in my app to call a bash script that then goes on to call the package. This runs fine locally.

However, I have also deployed the app to Heroku using Travis - over there, the views designed to activate the bash scripts do not run. I'm running a before_deploy script to install the required packages and the Travis build says they are successfully installed; I don't think the packages are available to the Heroku app.

My question is: is it possible for the required packages to be available in the Heroku app? And if so, how can I configure Heroku to run them via bash or some other means? Any help would be really appreciated!

It may be useful to know that the app is running in a Linux environment, and that I'm using a single Python build pack.

#### Code

My `.travis.yml` file is as follows:

```
sudo: true
language: python
python:
- '3.6'
env:
- DJANGO=2.1.5
install:
- pip install -q Django==$DJANGO
- pip install -q -r requirements.txt
script:
- python manage.py test
before_deploy:
- "./before_deploy.sh"
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: <REDACTED>
  app: hasnetdt-stage
notifications:
  email: false
```

And here is the `before_deploy.sh` script for reference:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:hvr/ghc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y cabal-install-1.22 ghc-7.10.2
sudo apt-get install -y graphviz

export PATH=~/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.10.2/bin:$PATH
cabal sandbox init
cabal update
cabal install alex happy
cabal install hindent hlint
```

#### Sidenote:

When I tried deploying locally (i.e. with `git push heroku master`), the Heroku logs said:

```
2019-03-24T18:41:29.637402+00:00 app[web.1]: ./static/scripts/prettify.sh: line 3: hindent: command not found
2019-03-24T18:41:29.644886+00:00 app[web.1]: ./static/scripts/linter.sh: line 3: hlint: command not found
```

But this may be because I deployed it locally rather than with Travis, so the before_deploy script isn't running.

Comment: After `cabal sandbox init`, cabal will install in `.cabal-sandbox/bin`.  Is this directory on your PATH?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @bergey. No, it wasn't on my path; however, I removed that line from the before_deploy script and the result was the same. I think the packages are being installed but not actually being deployed in heroku.